# PHP: Exploding string => last element is empty, but not recognized as empty

Tags: php, explode

I'm struggling with a behaviour in PHP and finally needed to sign up on stackoverflow as I could not find any answer to my problem for the very first time! :D

In my code, I'm getting the following content from a textarea (multiple lines):

```
10001;11;;;1;3;
10002;11;;;1;3;
10003;11;;;1;3;
```

I'm first exploding the several lines with `explode("\n", $string);`.
Second, I explode the elements of each line: `explode(";", $string[0]);`

The content of key 6 is empty, but PHP only recognizes the last element of the last line as empty:

Exploding the lines with

```
explode("\n", $string);

Array ( [0] => 10001;11;;;1;3; [1] => 10002;11;;;1;3; [2] => 10003;11;;;1;3; )
```

Exploding first line with

```
explode(";", $string[0]);

Array ( [0] => 10001 [1] => 11 [2] => [3] => [4] => 1 [5] => 3 [6] => )
```

Is last element of first line empty?

```
( if(empty($line1[6]) )
```

No.

Exploding second line with

```
explode(";", $string[1]);

Array ( [0] => 10002 [1] => 11 [2] => [3] => [4] => 1 [5] => 3 [6] => )
```

Is last element of second line empty?

```
( if(empty($line2[6]) )
```

No.

Exploding third line with

```
explode(";", $string[2]);

Array ( [0] => 10003 [1] => 11 [2] => [3] => [4] => 1 [5] => 3 [6] => )
```

Is last element of third line empty?

```
( if(empty($line3[6]) )
```

Yes

Can anyone tell me, why PHP always says that only the last element of the last line is empty, although every last element is?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the line endings are `\r\n`, not `\n`. You can use `PHP_EOL` instead of `"\n"` for your initial explode. You can see what the lines do contain if they aren't empty, with `var_dump($line1[6]);`

Comment: Not reproducible, using the code shown, and the assumption that lines end with `\n`: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/94a87d8756022da33f727c60fc7cc21e860eb761. But, reproducible if, as anyber suggests, the line ends are in fact `\r\n`: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5a10fa179a1a0ad5d118beba4901f7c63284b1a1

Comment: Add your form code.  And tell us browser and platform.

Comment: `array_map('trim', explode("\n", $string))`

Comment: P.S. var_dump gives you more detailed feedback than print_r, including the lengths of strings - whose contents may not include any visible characters....

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers!!! @aynber was right, if I explode the lines with \r\n or PHP_EOL, every last element is recognized empty.

Comment: @ADyson var_dump is definitely something I will use in future instead of print_r, thanks for that hint! :-)

Comment: @Patrick be careful with PHP_EOL, it will be platform dependent.  You can use it for writes for line separation in say log files.  E.g. on Windows it is different to Linux.  Your script could behave differently on different platforms.

Comment: @Progrock Thanks! So you would suggest using \r\n to explode lines breakes in textarea forms?

Comment: @Patrick you could assume carriage return line feeds, but don't necessarily trust user input.  Be very careful with untrusted data.  So depends on use case.

Comment: @Progrock Thank you very much for your explanation! I really appreciate the help of you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is normalising the line separation with carriage return line feeds.  So when you split on a line feed, you still have a carriage return in the last part.

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['data'];

$lines = explode("\n", $data);
//$lines = preg_split('@\R@', $data);

foreach($lines as $line) {
    $parts = explode(';', $line);
    var_dump(empty($parts[6]));
}
?>
<form method='POST'>
    <textarea name='data'>10001;11;;;1;3;
10002;11;;;1;3;
10003;11;;;1;3;</textarea>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Output (without the form code upon form submission):

```
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

Swap the explode line for the preg_split one above and the output is:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

\R escape sequence matches any Unicode newline sequence. (Please correct this definition if wrong.)

Note trailing space could be an issue.  Be careful with user input.